# cannot get all data xml when loop

Tags: php, html, mysql, xml

i have problem, i want get all data from my xml file in many tags name.
but when i loop, just get one in first tag. sory my english.

this is my code and sample format xml.

Code:

```
$xml = @simplexml_load_file('C://xampp/htdocs/logxml.xml'); 
foreach ($xml->children() as $b){ 
    echo $MakeAndModel = $b->{'xdm:ComponentGroup'}->{'xdm:Component'}->{'dd:DigitalS‌​torageTypeEnum'}; 
}

 <xdm:ComponentGroup>
 <xdm:Component id="dev1300" componentType="digitalStorage">
 <dd:DigitalStorageTypeEnum>harddisk</dd:DigitalStorageTypeEnum>
 <dd:Capacity>
 <dd:MaxCapacity>16</dd:MaxCapacity>
 <dd:Unit>bytes</dd:Unit>
 </dd:Capacity>
 </xdm:Component>
 </xdm:ComponentGroup> 

 <xdm:Component id="dev1350" componentType="digitalStorage">
 <dd:DigitalStorageTypeEnum>ram</dd:DigitalStorageTypeEnum>
 <dd:Capacity>
 <dd:MaxCapacity>1040187392</dd:MaxCapacity>
 <dd:Unit>bytes</dd:Unit>
 </dd:Capacity>
 </xdm:Component>
```

output = hardisk, no one else

and below of my real xml file still have many same tags name that i want to get the value. but it doesn't work. anyone help please.

Comment: Please post textual code, not links to external images.

Comment: Add your code in to question not as comment. Also add xml as code not image

Comment: *below of my real xml file still have many same tags name that i want to get the value* where?

Comment: like 'ram'.. because have same tag

Comment: i already edit my post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of problems, the main one is being hidden by your use of `@` which is hiding any problems it may have loading the XML file.  I've corrected the file so that it is now...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xdm:ComponentGroup xmlns:xdm="http://www.hp.com/schemas/imaging/con/xdm/1.1/"
    xmlns:dd="http://www.hp.com/schemas/imaging/con/dictionaries/1.0/">
    <xdm:Component id="dev1300" componentType="digitalStorage">
        <dd:DigitalStorageTypeEnum>harddisk</dd:DigitalStorageTypeEnum>
        <dd:Capacity>
            <dd:MaxCapacity>16</dd:MaxCapacity>
            <dd:Unit>bytes</dd:Unit>
        </dd:Capacity>
    </xdm:Component>

    <xdm:Component id="dev1350" componentType="digitalStorage">
        <dd:DigitalStorageTypeEnum>ram</dd:DigitalStorageTypeEnum>
        <dd:Capacity>
            <dd:MaxCapacity>1040187392</dd:MaxCapacity>
            <dd:Unit>bytes</dd:Unit>
        </dd:Capacity>
    </xdm:Component>
</xdm:ComponentGroup>
```

I've added a few dummy url's for the namespaces, but there are probably legitimate ones you can use for your case.

Then, using XPath to fetch the various components, you can load the file and output it using...

```
    <?php
    error_reporting ( E_ALL );
    ini_set ( 'display_errors', 1 );

    $xml = simplexml_load_file('NewFile.xml');
    $xml->registerXPathNamespace("xdm", "http://www.hp.com/schemas/imaging/con/xdm/1.1/");
    $xml->registerXPathNamespace("dd", "http://www.hp.com/schemas/imaging/con/dictionaries/1.0/");
    $components = $xml->xpath("//xdm:Component");
    foreach ($components as $component){
        $digitalStorageTypeEnum = $component->xpath("descendant::dd:DigitalStorageTypeEnum/text()")[0];
        echo $component['id']."-". $digitalStorageTypeEnum.PHP_EOL;
    }
```

This registers the namespaces as it references them in the XPath expressions.  So it first looks for all `<xdm:Component>` elements and then within that it fetches the `dd:DigitalStorageTypeEnum` elements.  Although the `text()` is only one piece of text, `xpath` always returns an array, so just take the first result as the content.

This outputs:

```
dev1300-harddisk
dev1350-ram
```

Comment: i have question, for code in rows registerxpathnamespace, after 'xdm' or 'dd', what url i put ?

Comment: I've updated the code and XML with namespaces which I've found somewhere on the Internet which seem to correspond to what your doing.  The main thing is that the URL must match between the XML and the PHP.

Comment: i get it, try update some code and it work now. thank for u code and respond Nigel.

Comment: Good to hear it's working.  Can you mark it as answered.

Answer (score 0):

bug here:

```
 </xdm:ComponentGroup> (element close)
```

you have to put it at the bottom of xml

```
<xdm:ComponentGroup>
     <xdm:Component id="dev1300" componentType="digitalStorage">
     <dd:DigitalStorageTypeEnum>harddisk</dd:DigitalStorageTypeEnum>
     <dd:Capacity>
     <dd:MaxCapacity>16</dd:MaxCapacity>
     <dd:Unit>bytes</dd:Unit>
     </dd:Capacity>
     </xdm:Component>
     <xdm:Component id="dev1350" componentType="digitalStorage">
     <dd:DigitalStorageTypeEnum>ram</dd:DigitalStorageTypeEnum>
     <dd:Capacity>
     <dd:MaxCapacity>1040187392</dd:MaxCapacity>
     <dd:Unit>bytes</dd:Unit>
     </dd:Capacity>
     </xdm:Component>
      </xdm:ComponentGroup>
```